# How do I change Javascript without restarting the server?

Tags: javascript, phoenix-framework, brunch

I can't seem to change any of my JavaScript files without restarting  the server - it really kills a lot of the live-reloading fun of working in Phoenix. I don't do a ton of JavaScript, so I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong.

Phoenix version: 1.2.0

Steps to reproduce:

1. Create a new project with `mix phoenix.new foo`
2. Create `web/static/js/foo.js` file.
3. In that file, write `alert("Hello, world!");`
4. In `app.js`, include `import "web/static/js/foo"` at the bottom.
5. Start Phoenix with `mix phoenix.server` and navigate to `localhost:4000`.
6. It doesn't matter how many times you refresh the page, you'll see an alert box with "Hello world!" every time, without fail.
7. Edit the `foo.js` message to be "Hello worlds!"
8. I expect that I'll still get an alert message with updated text, but the alert boxes stop appearing - altogether. They only start appearing again when I restart the server.

Is this intended behavior? A bug in Phoenix? Am I writing my JS code in a way that Brunch doesn't expect it? Is this a Babel issue? Should I be organizing my code differently?

Should add that I'm developing in Chrome on Linux - in case this might be a browser issue

Edit: I can't reproduce this exact issue anymore, but I'm still having issues with my non-toy project:

My original issue was in the app I'm actually developing - where I have `global.jQuery = require("jquery")` and `global.bootstrap = require("bootstrap")` in `app.js`. If I comment those two lines, save, and uncomment, I get a Javascript error in the browser: `app.js:16Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'jquery' from 'web/static/js/app.js'`

Comment: What do you get when just reloading browser instead of server ? Well you need to understand java script runs at client side.

Comment: "but the alert boxes stop appearing - altogether" Do you get any errors (possibly related to Brunch) in the terminal where you started `mix phoenix.server`? Do you get any error in the JS console in the browser? Does the JS file contain the new content if you access it directly from localhost:4000?

Comment: @Jits I covered that in my reproduction steps.

Comment: @Dogbert No errors in the terminal, and no JS errors in the Chrome console. I haven't navigated directly to the JS file in the browser - that's a good idea. I'll do that tomorrow (It's 3am where I am - posting before bed)

Comment: Hmm. I can no longer reproduce this exact issue. My original issue was in the app I'm actually developing - where I have `global.jQuery = require("jquery")` and `global.bootstrap = require("bootstrap")` in `app.js`. If I comment those two lines, save, and uncomment, I get a Javascript error in the browser: `app.js:16Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'jquery' from 'web/static/js/app.js'`

Comment: @Jits not if you use nodejs server..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Is this intended behavior? Yes.
- A bug in Phoenix? No.
- Am I writing my JS code in a way that Brunch doesn't expect it? Right you are.
- Is this a Babel issue? Nope.
- Should I be organizing my code differently? Probably.

Brunch (or Node.js or any other module bundler) expects relative path in `import` statement: it fails to resolve `web/static/js/foo` from `web/static/js/app.js` and does not mark `foo.js` as dependency of `app.js` (entry point). That is why it does not rebuild `app.js` when `foo.js` is changed. When Brunch is restarted, it completely rebuilds `app.js`, with latest `foo.js` (Brunch includes it because of `joinTo.javascripts` in config) version from the disk.

Specify relative paths (`import "./foo"`) and prefer `import jquery from ...` over `global.jquery = ...`

Comment: This is super useful! So how does Brunch know which files have changed? I thought it would (in Phoenix by default) look under `web/static`, where foo.js is housed. Shouldn't Brunch see that change and update? Brunch is pretty opaque to me

Answer (score 0):

Disable caching (if enabled) in your client (browser).
Disable caching (if enabled) in your server.

Comment: Didn't work. I'm reloading with `Ctrl-Shift-R` and disabling the cache in the developer tools, and Phoenix doesn't have caching by default.